# After installing wine with a .pkg, I get the error wine: command not found when running from the terminal but the app works fine

Tags: macos, command-line, wine

I have installed wine through a .pkg from [here](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html). `Wine Stable.app` works fine, but when I run any wine-related command from the terminal, I get `command not found`.

Comment: It's impossible. It will never add wine commands, no matter how much you try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wine related commands are not in the path so you have to add them:

(this is for if you installed it for all users, if it's for only your user put `~/Applications` instead of `/Applications`)

```bash
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine /usr/local/bin/wine
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winecfg /usr/local/bin/winecfg
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/msiexec /usr/local/bin/msiexec
```

If you installed 64-bit wine also: `sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wine64 /usr/local/bin/wine64`

Optional:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/notepad /usr/local/bin/notepad
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/regedit /usr/local/bin/regedit
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/regsvr32 /usr/local/bin/regsvr32
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineboot /usr/local/bin/wineboot
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineconsole /usr/local/bin/wineconsole
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winedbg /usr/local/bin/winedbg
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winefile /usr/local/bin/winefile
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winepath /usr/local/bin/winepath
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/wineserver /usr/local/bin/wineserver
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/start/bin/appdb /usr/local/bin/appdb
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app/Contents/Resources/wine/bin/winehelp /usr/local/bin/winehelp
```

Answer (score -1):

As of being stupid, I found an answer.

```
brew install wine
```

It's t h a t simple.

Before typing the command above,

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I might delete the comment above.

Comment: That is not simple it installs a package manager Homebrew which is an important decision to make.